# Two-node VMware HA cluster - admission control policy?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, high-availability

I normally setup larger clusters than a 2-node cluster with shared storage, but we have built a cluster specifically for hardware based GPU's for a  few VMs and thus new hardware and just a 2-node cluster with backend shared SAN storage.

The 2 hosts have 384GB RAM and dual 10 core procs.

Total VM count = 12 with total vCPU assigned equaling 36
Total VM cpu utilization is around 5% on each, and 35% ram on each.

My question is:

Is there a preference or best practice on the host admission policy?  Right now I have it set to "cluster tolerates 1 host failure" but typically I would set cpu/ram percentages with larger clusters.  However, when I do this regardless of setting (25/25, 15/15, 50/50) I end up with VM's showing "unprotected".  Setting it back to a single host failure sets them all back to "protected".

Are there certain settings for HA and DRS to take into consideration when only dealing with a 2 host cluster?

The cluster is currently running on 5.1 but I don't think the options have changed since.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Should VMware HA Admission Control be enabled for small (2/3-host) clusters?](https://serverfault.com/questions/515695/should-vmware-ha-admission-control-be-enabled-for-small-2-3-host-clusters)

Don't enable admission control for a 2-host environment. Unless you're dealing with well-calculated or custom slot sizes or VMs or resource pools with reservations, there's no benefit to doing this.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know how I missed that one in the search, but after reading your discussion there it makes sense.  I'll go with that!

Comment: I think VMware provides bad information about this stuff. The defaults are terrible and understanding resource math is tough.

Comment: @TheCleaner: You can view the "calculated" slot size by clicking `Advanced Runtime Info` on the cluster summary page. As an aside, Hyper-V uses only allocated RAM as the slot size determinant.